# Nested stack dependency

Tags: ros, stack, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assume stack A depends on ros stack and its stack.xml file has " and assume that I create another stack B which depends on stack A and stack ros. If B's stack.xml specifies , does stack B also inherit "ros" stack as its dependency or do I need to explicitly specify  as well? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12160/nested-stack-dependency/) by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2011-11-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on how the stack dependency is converted -- if it is used to generate debian package dependencies, then, yes, it is inherited.

That said, it is better to explicitly enumerate your actual dependencies.  For example, an intermediary stack can change its dependencies, and so you might suddenly be without this implicit dependency.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4